# How to get a frequency equation from limited power expansion of differential equation solution?

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion, nonlinear

I am trying to extract frequency that is variable depended from nonlinear coupled differential equation.  I managed to get a solution in form of power series expansion up to 8th term and possible more. But I failed to figure out how to extract frequency from series symbolically and use its parameters to determine if frequency is real or complex (which is my objective).  To illustrate a point, I use a toy model of coupled system shown below,

```
 equation={x''[t]+ax'[t]+bx[t]-cy[t]==0, y''-ay'+by-cx==0,x[t]==1,y[t]==0,x'[t]==0,y'[t]==0}
 s1=DSolve[equation,{x[t],y[t]},t]
 f1=FourierSinTransform[s1,t,w]
 freq=Solve[Denominator[f1],w]
```

Using analytical solution of simple toy example I was able to get frequency functions listed in $freq$ that are dependent on parameters $a,b,c$.  With nonlinear system, it is impossible to find analytical solution but I managed to get power expansion form solution.  Is it possible to get frequencies from power expansion?  I tested this method with toy model as shown below,

```
 series=AsymptoticDSolveValue[equation,{x[t],y[t]},{t,0,10}
 fs=FourierSinTransform[series,t,w]
```

and one gets a different solution due to limited number of terms in power expansion.  It does not gets better with more terms.  Are there other methods?  My last resort is Monte Carlo method.

Note:

1. In general, the expected solution to nonlinear system is in form of $x=Ae^{w_1t}+Be^{w_2t}+Ce^{w_3t}+De^{w_4t}$ just like in linear system,
2. I used my own series algorithm to get power expansion.

Comment: The series solution generated by `AsymptoticDSolveValue` is not bounded (oscillating), there is no notion of frequency for it, or how do you define frequency? what is "a frequency equation"?

Comment: If you look at my note: 1) the expected solution has exp(wt) form.  I am looking for way to determine w which will be composed of a,b,c,  Thus why I called w as frequency function.

Comment: A similar form of solution can be expected for Hamiltonian systems (quasiperiodic solution), but a solution might not exist for all initial conditions if your system is not integrable (some initial conditions might be chaotic, thus can't be expressed in an analytic form). Frequencies will also depend on initial values, not only on parameters. This is a feature of nonlinear systems. For Hamiltonian systems, you can use canonical perturbation theory or some variant of normal forms based on the algebra of Poison brackets.

Comment: For generic flows perturbation expansion based on Lie brackets of vector fields can be used. See Deprit 's algorithm or other methods used in celestial mechanics. E.g. in Leo Michelotti, Intermediate Classical Dynamics. If you want linear frequencies, just expand your vector field to the first order and solve corresponding linear system directly.

Comment: I did Taylor power expansion of nonlinear terms and solved for frequencies I am looking for.  However, the control parameters (a,b,c)  that were supposed to give me Real frequencies gave me incorrect plots of x and y at those frequencies.  That means that linearization of nonlinear terms approach is not correct.